# How can I start another file within a program using startfile and relative path?

Tags: python, execution

dirA/dirB/dirC/program.py

dirA/dirD/target.py

How can I initiate the execution of target.py by program.py? I tried to use os.startfile(".\.\.\dirD\target.py") but unfortunately, it does not work. Have not found anything which helped.

Program.py should be closed. Also, it should be based on a relative path since the scripts will be used on multiple machines!

Comment: first check if `program.py` runs in `dirA/dirB/dirC` - it could be started in different folder (`os.getcwd()` - `CWD` means `Current Working Directory`) and now your relative path can't find `target.py`. It is common problem when you create link on desktop or in system's menu

Answer (score 1):

Use `subprocess.Popen`, and invoke it with python.

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.Popen(['python', r'../target.py'])
```

If you use `Popen` as the last line that is executed in `program.py`, the new script will be started and the `program.py` will exit.

Note that you can use `os.path.abspath()` to turn a relative path into an absolute path if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I need a solution which allows me to close program.py while invoking target.py by using relative paths only

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. Is there not a possibility to use os.startfile() and access the desired directories by using the relative path method?

Comment: @cspecial What error do you get when trying `Popen`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the pathlib-module and os.startfile().

pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent returns the desired directory so that os.startfile(str(pathlib.Path(**file**).parent) + [path]) executes the file.